# Why can the general quintic be transformed to $v^5-5\beta v^3+10\beta^2v-\beta^2 = 0$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, gr.group-theory, polynomials

The quintic can be transformed to the one-parameter *Brioschi quintic*,

$$u^5-10\alpha u^3+45\alpha^2u-\alpha^2 = 0\tag1$$

This form is well-known for its connection to the symmetries of the icosahedron. I found that using a similar transformation, the general quintic can be reduced, also in radicals, to,

$$v^5-5\beta v^3+10\beta^2v-\beta^2 = 0\tag2$$

**Question:** Does $(2)$ appear anywhere when studying icosahedral symmetry or similar objects? If not, then what is the reason *why* the quintic can be reduced, in radicals, to this one-parameter form?

**P.S.** Incidentally, doing the transformation $u = 1/(x^2+20)$ on $(1)$ and $v = 4/(y^2+15)$ on $(2)$ reduces them to the rather nice similar forms,

$$(x^2+20)^2(x-5)+\frac{1}{\alpha}=0\tag3$$

$$(y^2+15)^2(y-5)+\frac{32}{\beta}=0\tag4$$

Answer (score 1):

Geometry behind the Brioschi quintic is explained in Jerry Shurman book "Geometry of the Quintic" (available from his website http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/ ). However, it seems no explanation of (2) is given there.

Comment: My feeling is that since it is not trivial to reduce the quintic to one-parameter form, then there ***has*** to be some reason (geometric or other) why it can transformed into something so similar to the Brioschi form. Note that it is also very reminiscent to the  _solvable_ DeMoivre quintic $$x^5-5\alpha\, x^3+5\alpha^2 x+\beta = 0$$