# On level $6$ of the McKay–Thompson series of the Monster and Apéry numbers, et al

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, modular-forms, binomial-coefficients

After the McKay–Thompson series of levels $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ of the Monster were mentioned in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446437/12905), level $6$ has very interesting relations as well. (*Level **10** is in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446654/12905).*)

---

**I. Level-6 functions**

Given the Dedekind eta function $\eta(\tau)$, define,

$$j_{6A} = \left(\sqrt{j_{6B}} + \frac{\color{blue}{-1}}{\sqrt{j_{6B}}}\right)^2 =\left(\sqrt{j_{6C}} + \frac{\color{blue}8}{\sqrt{j_{6C}}}\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt{j_{6D}} + \frac{\color{blue}9}{\sqrt{j_{6D}}}\right)^2-4$$

where,

\begin{align}
j_{6B} &= \left(\frac{\eta(2\tau)\,\eta(3\tau)}{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(6\tau)}\right)^{12}\\
j_{6C} &= \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(3\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)\,\eta(6\tau)}\right)^{6}\\
j_{6D} &= \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(2\tau)}{\eta(3\tau)\,\eta(6\tau)}\right)^{4}\\
j_{6E} &= \left(\frac{\eta(2\tau)\,\eta^3(3\tau)}{\eta(\tau)\,\eta^3(6\tau)}\right)^{3}.
\end{align}

Then Conway and Norton found (or a version thereof) that,

$$j_{6A}+2j_{6E} = j_{6B}+j_{6C}+j_{6D}+14.$$

They found similar relations for levels $6$, $10$, $12$, $18$, $30$.

---

**II. Sequences**

I found we can use the blue numbers of the square and near-square relations above to get ***four*** known sequences. Starting with Cooper's sequence $s_6=s_{6A}$, one derives the Apéry numbers, Domb numbers, and Almkvist–Zudilin numbers,

\begin{align}
s_{6A}(k) &=\binom{2k}{k}\sum_{m=0}^k \binom{k}{m}^3 =1, 4, 60, 1120, 24220,\ldots\\
s_{6B}(j) &=\sum_{k=0}^j (\color{blue}{-u})^{j-k}\binom{j+k}{j-k}\,s_{6A}(k) =1, 5, 73, 1445, 33001,\ldots\\
s_{6C}(j) &=\sum_{k=0}^j (\color{blue}{-v})^{j-k}\binom{j+k}{j-k}\,s_{6A}(k) =1, -4, 28, -256, 2716,\ldots\\
s_{6D}(n) &=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^j (\color{blue}{-w})^{n-j}\binom{n+j}{n-j}\binom{j}{k}\binom{2j}{j}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}s_{6A}(k)  \\
&=1, -3, 9, -3, -279, 2997,\ldots
\end{align}

where $u = \color{blue}{-1}$, $v = \color{blue}8$, and $w = \color{blue}9$, respectively.

---

**III. Alternative forms**

However, the three sequences derived from $s_{6A}$ have *simpler* alternative closed-forms,

\begin{align}
s_{6A}(k) &=\binom{2k}{k}\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}^3 =1, 4, 60, 1120, 24220,\ldots\\
s_{6B}(k) &=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}^2\binom{k+j}{j}^2 =1, 5, 73, 1445, 33001,\ldots\\
s_{6C}(k) &= (-1)^k \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}^2 \binom{2(k-j)}{k-j} \binom{2j}{j} =1, -4, 28, -256, 2716,\ldots\\
s_{6D}(k) &=\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j}\,3^{k-3j}\,\frac{(3j)!}{j!^3} \binom{k}{3j} \binom{k+j}{j} =1, -3, 9, -3, -279, 2997,\ldots.
\end{align}

All have a $3$-term recurrence relations. Two significant roles of these sequences are, if within the radius of convergence, then,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty s_{6A}(k)\,\frac{1}{\;\big(j_{6A}\big)^{k+1/2}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty s_{6B}(k)\,\frac{1}{\;\big(j_{6B}\big)^{k+1/2}} = \\ \sum_{k=0}^\infty s_{6C}(k)\,\frac{1}{\;\big(j_{6C}\big)^{k+1/2}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty s_{6D}(k)\,\frac{1}{\;\big(j_{6D}\big)^{k+1/2}}$$

as well as yielding formulas for $1/\pi$. (See also *[Ramanujan–Sato series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series#Level_6)*.)

---

**IV. Questions**

1. How do we transform the closed-forms of Section 2 into the alternative ones in Section 3?
2. In general, is there a method to simplify binomial sums, especially to reduce the triple summation $s_{6D}$ into into simpler version in Section 3? (And the [level-$10$ sequences](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446654/12905) do not yet have alternative closed-forms.)